# No access to the WordPress appearance panel

Tags: wordpress

I am struggling with one thing I am not so into and any extra help could help.

I just received the WordPress website from the design company. The agreement was to make it editable, change more than just a content by the time. After the end of cooperation, I started to edit some parts of the website but there is no such an option as Appearance in my Wordpress option panel. I asked the developer how can I change basic CSS of some elements on the website but he argued that it is restricted to change any HTML or CSS because it might cause some errors in the code after rewriting it. I get it, but there should be another way to get to the files, how else I could style the new elements? Is there a no way to add Appearance option to the panel? I am not the expert, it just seems too unrealistic for me to say: it is restricted because of this and that and there is no way to add it. Any experience with that, please? Do we have to find Wordpress developer to go through it, or it is just the fact that I can not edit it anymore?

Thank you for any comment!

Best regard,

Miroslava

Comment: From the sound of it, seems like the account you're using to log in into the WP Dashboard doesn't have enough permissions to access the Appeareance menu (where you can indeed add some CSS rules via [the Customizer](https://themeisle.com/blog/wordpress-customizer-how-to/)). Check with your client and if that's the case then you basically won't be able to do anything (unless you happen to have FTP access to the server?)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily edit any wordpress appearance by edit the theme, take a look into wp-content/themes, there should be the files of the theme usually php and css files

Comment: I can customize menus, site identity settings such as icon or title and that's it. No other options there for me. I checked each subcategory in my WordPress and it is just not there, as in all another wordpress tutorials and WP guides :/

Comment: Do you have admin permission? If so you can write custom CSS in Appearance---Customize and then you can find Additional CSS option. You can write custom styling code. Check out this https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/